# How do I restart IIS (or single site) from a PHP page?

Tags: php, iis

When I was looking at Azure, there was an option to restart IIS from the web-based control panel: according to a friend of mine, the interface is just calling powershell scripts on the backend. My current VPS provider offers the same thing, restarting the web server from a web page.

I've tried

```
echo Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command "& {iisreset}"');
```

but get "Access Denied."

I've tried

```
echo Shell_Exec ('command.exe appcmd stop site "that_website"');
```

and it doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't work either.

Here's the goal: occasionally, PHP will go toes up (Fast-CGI process has stopped working) and my phone rings. I'd like to give the client the option to press a button and restart their site. What permissions do I need, and/or what code would do that?

Comment: Restarting IIS requires administrator permissions, which your VPS provider probably won't allow you to.

Comment: That wasn't my question. In any case, I have full administrative control of the box.

Comment: Your account might be an administrator, but your PHP code on IIS might not. The basic facts can always be neglected, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Answer (score 0):

I can get appcmd work when I modify your code to

```
echo Shell_Exec ('appcmd.exe stop site "website"');
```

[image]

If you want to do something like iireset with powershell in PHP, just try to change IIS manager->site node->basic settings->connect as-> specific user-> try to replace it to a domain administrator account.

But it is not recommended to do this operation in a PHP application.

When you are facing access denied error, try to use process monitor to troubleshooting this kind of issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon